# thinking sphinx yml file not being read

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, yaml, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

Thinking Sphinx works on my Rails app (Rails 3.2.1, TS 3.0.1) but when I set up a sphinx.yml file in the config folder, it doesn't seem to read the morphology instructions.

The file is called sphinx.yml and is in the config folder. Here is the yml format:

```
development:
  morphology: stem_en

production:
  morphology: stem_en
```

I copy/pasted this so the indentation matches wha'ts in my code. I don't use a libstemmer or haven't installed any other wordforms.

Please, I keep my fingers crossed someone can help me on this one as I'm stumped!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And the answer is: read ALL the doco on:
https://github.com/pat/thinking-sphinx/blob/master/README.textile

The new name for the .yml is thinking_sphinx.yml